# Discord.py mod log setup

Tags: command, discord.py, option-type

I was wondering how one could make a command that sets up a mod log for a certain server, or start logging in one that already exists. This will probably require a database or JSON, anything is fine, as long as I can get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is with a .txt file that would contain all of the logs. I would add a line every time an event within the guild occurred, you could configure this to whatever events you wanted.

```
import datetime

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open("logs.txt", "a") as logsFile:
        logsFile.write("\n[{}] {} just joined the server".format(datetime.datetime.now(), 
                                                                 member.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module for [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html) or any other libraries, you can also use it for logging your own messages, either using the same or a separate logger.